# Flutter Web & Player.js: How to control an iframe containing a video?

Tags: flutter, iframe, dart-html, dart-webui, dart-js-interop

I am trying to `programmatically stop and play` a video stream from `bunny.net` in an iframe placed in a stateful widget.

According to [**Bunny.net**](https://docs.bunny.net/docs/playback-control-api):
The Bunny.net Stream Player offers methods through its embeddable iframe player, enabling external programmatic interaction with the playback session. `The embeddable iframe player` employs the **player.js JavaScript library**.

Steps to implement this are mentioned [here](https://bunny.net/blog/introducing-player-js-support-for-bunny-stream-advanced-player-control-and-monitoring-api/). Also, I studied the [Player.js documentation](https://playerjs.com/docs/en=apicommands).

---

I wrote this code which displays the video along with its GUI controls:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _url = "https://iframe.mediadelivery.net/embed/2196455";
    _iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..src = _url
      ..id = 'iframe0'
      ..allowFullscreen = true;
      
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'iframeElement', (int viewId) => _iframeElement);

    super.initState();
  }
```

---

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
            child: HtmlElementView(
              viewType: 'iframeElement',
            ),
    );
  }
```

Using the above two guidelines of how to control video playback from Bunny.net using Player.js, I tried stopping the video like this:

```
 IFrameElement iframe = querySelector('#iframe0') as IFrameElement;
 iframe.contentWindow!.postMessage({"api": "stop"}, "*");

 IFrameElement iframe2 =
   document.getElementById("iframe0")! as IFrameElement;
 iframe2.contentWindow!.postMessage({"api": "stop"}, "*");
```

Nothing happens, and no errors occur.

I tried adding this to the index.html file, but still nothing happened.

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="//assets.mediadelivery.net/playerjs/player-0.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    const player=new playerjs.Player(document.getElementById("iframe0"));
    player.on('stop', () => {
    log("stop");
    });
</script>
```

**Any ideas on how to correctly solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to solve the issue itself, but please pay attention that you are using player.js library but referring to [playerjs.com](https://playerjs.com) documentation. These are two different projects.

Cheers!